# Finding the largest time overlap in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to do this on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
parent_id INT
child_id INT
start_time TIME
end_time TIME
```

You should look at the children as sub-processes that run for the parent program. All these sub-processes are run once every day, and each child run within its given time span. I want to find the largest overlap of time intervals for each parent based on the times of its children, i.e. I want to know the longest possible overlap where all the sub-processes are running. The fact that each time span is repeated every day means that even if child's time interval spans midnight (i.e. 23:00-10:00), it can overlap with a child that only runs in the morning (i.e. 07:00-09:00), because even if they don't overlap on "the first day", they will overlap on all subsequent days.

The output should look like this:

```
parent_id INT
start_time TIME
end_time TIME
valid BIT
```

Where `valid = 1` if an overlap was found and `valid = 0` if no overlap was found.

A couple of important pieces of information:

1. A time interval can span midnight, i.e. `start_time = 23:00` and `end_time = 03:00`, which is a time interval of 4 hours.
2. Two time intervals may overlap in two different places, i.e. `start_time1 = 13:00`, `end_time1 = 06:00`, `start_time2 = 04:00`, `end_time2 = 14:00`. This would give the largest overlap as 04:00 - 06:00 = 2 hours.
3. There may be no overlap common for the children of a given parent, in which case the out put for that parent would be `start_time = NULL`, `end_time = NULL` and `valid = 0`.
4. If a child interval spans the whole day, then `start_time = NULL` and `end_time = NULL`. This was chosen to avoid having a day as 00:00-24:00, which would slice overlaps crossing midnight in two, i.e. parent 3 below would end up having two overlaps (23:00-24:00 and 00:00 - 004:00), in stead of one (23:00-04:00).
5. An overlap is only an overlap if the time interval is shared by all the children of a parent.
6. The time span of one child can never be longer than 24 hours.

Take this example:

```
parent_id  child_id  start_time  end_time
    1         1           06:00     14:00
    1         2           13:00     09:00
    1         3           07:00     09:00
    2         1           12:00     17:00
    2         2           09:00     11:00
    3         1            NULL      NULL
    3         2           23:00     04:00
    4         1            NULL      NULL
    4         2            NULL      NULL
   10         1           06:11     14:00
   10         2           06:00     09:00
   10         3           05:00     08:44
   11         1           11:38     17:00
   11         2           09:02     12:11
```

These data would produce this result set:

```
parent_id  start_time  end_time  valid
    1           07:00     09:00    1
    2            NULL      NULL    0
    3           23:00     04:00    1
    4            NULL      NULL    1
   10           06:11     08:44    1
   11           11:38     12:11    1
```

The overlap for a parent is the time interval that is shared by all its children. So the overlap for parent 10 is found by finding the overlap where all 3 children share time:
Child 1 (06:11-14:00) and 2 (06:00-09:00) overlap from 06:11 to 09:00. This overlap time interval is then applied to child 3 (05:00-08:44), which gives an overlap of 06:11 to 08:44, since this interval is the only interval where all 3 children share common time.

I hope this makes sense.

I can do it with a cursor, but I would really prefer to avoid cursors. I have been wracking my brain about how to do it without cursors, but I have come up short. Is there any way of doing it without cursors?

EDIT: Expanded the text for clause 4, to explain the decision of having a full day be NULL to NULL, in stead of 00:00 to 00:00.
EDIT: Expanded the examples with two more cases. The new cases have parent ID 10 and 11.
EDIT: Inserted explanation of how the overlap for parent 10 is found.
EDIT: Clarified clause 3. Added clauses 5 and 6. Went into detail about what this is all about.

Comment: i don't understand row 3 in your output as there is no overlap?

Comment: @Tanner: clause 4 says that there is overlap in that case.

Comment: @jbang: clause is a real nuisance and not intuitive at all.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman i guess so yeh, not easy to understand. are we to assume that a default time span is from midnight to midnight to judge that there has been an overlap?

Comment: ps i think you're going to need to use a [cte](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to solve this.

Comment: Is it only full hours in the data, or are there also minutes and seconds?

Comment: Isn't the correct answer to parent 1 13:00 - 09:00 since it overlaps with child 1 1 + 3 hours?

Comment: @IsaacKleinman: Which clause is not intuitive at all? #4? The reason for that can be found in the underlying data. So I can't change it. Apart from the underlying data defining clause 4, it also helps to avoid splitting a time interval, just because an arbitrary decision have made 00:00 - 24:00 a day. That would split any overlap at midnight, which we don't want.

Comment: @Tanner: What do you mean by "a default time span"? We don't have a default time span. Which is one of the reasons behind a full day being NULL - NULL, rather than 00:00 - 24:00.

Comment: looking at your data though it appears that time spans can cross more than one day. so i assume the start time is always on the same day.

Comment: @JamesZ: 13:00 - 09:00 is not an overlap, it is the time interval for child 2. There are 3 children to parent 1. Child 1 has the interval 06:00 - 14:00, child 2 13:00 - 09:00 and child 3 07:00 - 09:00. Child 1 and child 2 have 2 overlaps: 13:00 - 14:00 and 06:00 - 09:00. These 2 overlaps combined with child 3 gives one single overlap: 07:00 - 09:00.

Comment: @Tanner: One child's time span cannot be longer than 24 hours, so a time span can't cross more than one day. The longest time span would be NULL - NULL, which is 24 hours. Any other time span would be less than 24 hours, i.e. 00:01 - 23:59.

Comment: @dean: There are also minutes. I avoided them for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @Tanner: Do you mean a recursive CTE, where each recursion would find the overlap between 2 children or a child and the previously found overlap?

Comment: So the longest overlap is the total overlap of _all_ the children of the parent, not just any 2 of them?

Comment: If I understood correctly, your example would be more clear if the 1 - 3 would have time 07:00 - 10:00 and then the result would be 07:00 - 09:00

Comment: @JamesZ: Precisely. The longest overlap still need to be an overlap for all children.

Comment: @JamesZ: I used 07:00 - 09:00 to show that times sometimes can be equal. I'm sorry if that confused more than it helped.

Comment: The only thing I can figure out that would work is to have a table of minutes (e.g. one row for each minute) and then join that to the table so that it takes one row for every minute inside the range and then gather those minutes where the count of rows = number of it's children and min / max is the start and end time + of course the rules for the nulls, but you can have null as all minutes and if the max count = 1 then there's no overlap

Comment: @JamesZ: I see what you mean, and I actually considered that solution at one point. But I can't figure out how to generate the "minute table" without using a cursor.

Comment: It might be best to just create a normal table with the times instead of calculating them, but it is possible to do that with a CTE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1787

Comment: @JamesZ: I looked at your code on sqlfiddle, and I have a vague idea about how it works. :-) But my actual problem was getting from the intervals in my data to having them 'spread out' over the minutes in your sqlfiddle code. My problem is that I'm not very good with CTEs. Do you maybe have a link to a good "Introduction to CTEs" text?

Comment: CTE is just a like a dynamic view, so it just does the select is in there and then you can refer to the results later to build different structures on top of it and that way you can create more complex structures like this (and you could do the same thing with derived tables too). That code just creates a big virtual table of number 1s, if I remember correctly 7*7*7*7 rows (the cross joins) and then assigns numbers to it (with row number over null) and then takes top 1440 rows and adds the number of minutes from 00:00 to the row making it a table of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I think your output should be:

```
parent_id   start_time  end_time    valid
1           07:00       09:00       1
2           NULL        NULL        0
3           23:00       04:00       1
4           NULL        NULL        1
10          06:11       08:44       1
11          11:38       12:11       1
```

And here is a set-based solution:

```
DECLARE @Times TABLE
(
    parent_id INT
    ,child_id INT
    ,start_time TIME
    ,end_time TIME
);

INSERT INTO @Times
VALUES
    (1,         1,           '06:00',     '14:00')
    ,(1,         2,           '13:00',     '09:00')
    ,(1,         3,           '07:00',     '09:00')
    ,(2,         1,           '12:00',     '17:00')
    ,(2,         2,           '09:00',     '11:00')
    ,(3,         1,            NULL,      NULL)
    ,(3,         2,           '23:00',     '04:00')
    ,(4,         1,            NULL,      NULL)
    ,(4,         2,            NULL,      NULL)
    ,(10,         1,           '06:11',     '14:00')
    ,(10,         2,           '06:00',     '09:00')
    ,(10,         3,           '05:00',     '08:44')
    ,(11,         1,           '11:38',     '17:00')
    ,(11,         2,           '09:02',     '12:11');


DECLARE @Parents TABLE
(
    parent_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,ChildCount INT
)
INSERT INTO @Parents
SELECT 
    parent_id
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT child_id) AS ChildCount
FROM
    @Times
GROUP BY 
    parent_id

DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME2 = '00:00'
DECLARE @MinutesInTwoDays INT = 2880
DECLARE @Minutes TABLE(ThisMinute DATETIME2 PRIMARY KEY);

WITH 
MinutesCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        1 AS MinuteNumber
        ,@StartTime AS ThisMinute

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        NextMinuteNumber
        ,NextMinute
    FROM MinutesCTE
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(MinuteNumber+1,DATEADD(MINUTE,1,ThisMinute))) NextDates(NextMinuteNumber,NextMinute)
    WHERE 
        NextMinuteNumber <= @MinutesInTwoDays
)
INSERT INTO @Minutes
SELECT ThisMinute FROM MinutesCTE M OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2880);


DECLARE @SharedMinutes TABLE
(
    ThisMinute DATETIME2 
    ,parent_id INT
    ,UNIQUE(ThisMinute,parent_id)
);

WITH TimesCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Times.parent_id
        ,Times.child_id
        ,CAST(ISNULL(Times.start_time,'00:00') AS datetime2) AS start_time
        ,
        DATEADD
        (   
            DAY
            ,
            CASE 
                WHEN Times.end_time IS NULL THEN 2
                WHEN Times.start_time > Times.end_time THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
            END
            ,CAST(ISNULL(Times.end_time,'00:00') AS datetime2)
        ) as end_time
    FROM
        @Times Times


    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Times.parent_id
        ,Times.child_id
        ,DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(Times.start_time as datetime2)) AS start_time
        ,DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(Times.end_time AS datetime2)) AS end_time
    FROM
        @Times Times
    WHERE
        start_time < end_time

)

--Get minutes shared by all children of each parent
INSERT INTO @SharedMinutes
SELECT 
    M.ThisMinute
    ,P.parent_id
FROM
    @Minutes M
JOIN
    TimesCTE T
    ON 
        M.ThisMinute BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
JOIN
    @Parents P
    ON T.parent_id = P.parent_id

GROUP BY 
    M.ThisMinute
    ,P.parent_id
    ,P.ChildCount
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT T.child_id) = P.ChildCount

--get results
SELECT
    parent_id
    ,CAST(CASE WHEN start_time = '1900-01-01' AND end_time = '1900-01-02 23:59' THEN NULL ELSE start_time END AS TIME) AS start_time
    ,CAST(CASE WHEN start_time = '1900-01-01' AND end_time = '1900-01-02 23:59' THEN NULL ELSE end_time END AS TIME) AS end_time
    ,valid
FROM
(
    SELECT
        P.parent_id
        ,MIN(ThisMinute) AS start_time
        ,MAX(ThisMinute) AS end_time
        ,CASE WHEN MAX(ThisMinute) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS valid 
    FROM
        @Parents P
    LEFT JOIN
        @SharedMinutes SM
        ON P.parent_id = SM.parent_id
    GROUP BY
        P.parent_id

) Results
```

You may find that the iterative algorithm you have outlined in your question would be more efficient. But I would use a WHILE loop instead of a cursor if you take that approach.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a very verbose method of achieving the desired results, but it works for the given dataset, although it should be tested with larger data.

I've simply joined the table to itself where the `parent_id` matches and the `child_id` is different to get all of the combinations of times that might overlap and then performed some `DATEDIFF`'s to calculate the difference, before filtering and grouping the output.

You can run the below in isolation to test and tweak if required:

```
-- setup initial table
CREATE TABLE #OverlapTable
    (
      [parent_id] INT ,
      [child_id] INT ,
      [start_time] TIME ,
      [end_time] TIME
    );

-- insert dummy data
INSERT  INTO #OverlapTable
        ( [parent_id], [child_id], [start_time], [end_time] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, '06:00', '14:00' ),
        ( 1, 2, '13:00', '09:00' ),
        ( 1, 3, '07:00', '09:00' ),
        ( 2, 1, '12:00', '17:00' ),
        ( 2, 2, '09:00', '11:00' ),
        ( 3, 1, NULL, NULL ),
        ( 3, 2, '23:00', '04:00' ),
        ( 4, 1, NULL, NULL ),
        ( 4, 2, NULL, NULL );

-- insert all combinations into a new temp table #Results with overlap calculations
SELECT  *
INTO    #Results
FROM    ( SELECT    t1.parent_id ,
                    t1.start_time ,
                    t1.end_time ,
                    t2.start_time AS t2_start_time ,
                    t2.end_time AS t2_end_time ,
                    CASE WHEN t1.start_time IS NULL
                              AND t1.end_time IS NULL THEN 0
                         WHEN t1.start_time BETWEEN t2.start_time
                                            AND     t2.end_time
                         THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, t1.start_time, t2.end_time)
                         WHEN t1.end_time BETWEEN t2.start_time AND t2.end_time
                         THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, t2.start_time, t1.end_time)
                         ELSE NULL
                    END AS Overlap
          FROM      #OverlapTable t1
                    INNER JOIN #OverlapTable t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.parent_id
                                                   AND t2.child_id != t1.child_id
        ) t

-- SELECT * FROM #Results -- this shows intermediate results

-- filter and group results with the largest overlaps and handle other cases
SELECT DISTINCT
        r.parent_id ,
        CASE WHEN r.Overlap IS NULL THEN NULL
             ELSE CASE WHEN r.start_time IS NULL THEN r.t2_start_time
                       ELSE r.start_time
                  END
        END start_time ,
        CASE WHEN r.Overlap IS NULL THEN NULL
             ELSE CASE WHEN r.end_time IS NULL THEN r.t2_end_time
                       ELSE r.end_time
                  END
        END end_time ,
        CASE WHEN r.Overlap IS NULL THEN 0
             ELSE 1
        END Valid
FROM    #Results r
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT parent_id ,
                        MAX(Overlap)
                 FROM   #Results
                 WHERE  r.parent_id = parent_id
                 GROUP BY parent_id
                 HAVING MAX(Overlap) = r.Overlap
                        OR ( MAX(Overlap) IS NULL
                             AND r.Overlap IS NULL
                           ) )

DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #OverlapTable
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you change the data, it doesn't seem to return correct results anymore: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1791 (changed data: 1, 2, '13:00', '08:00') -- it should show 07:00 - 08:00

Comment: @JamesZ i read the question as it should show the start and end time of the row that held the largest overlap, regardless of the overlapping portion. if it's is incorrect, i'll let the OP decide and delete this if it's incorrect or not useful to him.

Comment: That's how I also thought it was supposed to be, but the comment explains it "The longest overlap still need to be an overlap for all children"

Comment: Of course I can still be misunderstanding this, but the example case isn't that good because it has so many special cases there where the end times are the same.

Comment: @jbang if you can update the sample data and desired output with additional clear cut cases, I will modify the query if required.

Comment: @Tanner: JamesZ is correct. I need the start and end time of the actual overlap, not of the interval that gets closest. I will try to update the examples to be more clear cut.

Comment: Although it doesn't quite solve my problem, I do find this solution useful, but because I don't yet have enough reputation, I can't upvote it. Could someone please upvote it for me?

Comment: I have updated the examples with two new cases, which (hopefully) should make it clearer.